# autocomplete like google search while typing a character from sql in mvc.net

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to Implement Auto Complete (like google) in mvc.net, my requirement is i have text box, while typing in text box  want get data from SQL database, for example I entered 'A' as first character in text box for this character check matches in db and display in search text box, then I entered second character as 'AP' and it should search in db and find related data and so on. how this can be achieved using mvc.net. kindly provide some suggestions, how this can be done.

thanks

Comment: you have to investigate yourself, using search engine, documentation and tutorials, code something yourself, and in case you have specific problems with your code, you come here with them.

Comment: Hi Hoijui, I know i have to code myself, I m asking for suggestions, not for solutions , if possible provide some suggestions not comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I m able to achive auto complete on every key change by using below code.

Search TextBox:-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control control-label" id="txtnumber" onkeyup="checkSearchChanged()" placeholder="Search">
```

Javascript Code:-

```
function checkSearchChanged() {

    var currentValue = $('#txtnumber').val();
    var ajaxMethodUrl = "/Home/SearchNumber?SearchKeyword=" + currentValue;
    $("#txtnumber").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var customer = new Array();
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                type: "Get",
                url: ajaxMethodUrl,
                success: function (data) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                        customer[i] = { label: data[i], Id: data[i] };
                    }
                }
            });
            response(customer);
        }
    });
}
```

In Controller :-

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult SearchNumber(string SearchKeyword)
    {
       return Json(_Manager.SearchNumers(SearchKeyword), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In Bussiness Layer:-

```
 public List<string> SearchNumers(string SearchKeyword)
    {
        //Logic to return data from DataBase
    }
```

Thanks